# Inheriting an interface so add a setter to an existing property

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, repository

I was hoping to use inheritance to add a setter to an existing property. I want to do something like this:

```
public class MyObjectRepository<T> : IObjectRepository<T> where T : IRepositoryEntity
{
    private readonly List<T> _data = new List<T>();
    // ...
    public void Add(T model)
    {
        _data.Add(model);

        var managedModel = (IManagedRepositoryEntity)model;
        if (managedModel != null)
            managedModel.SetId(_data.LastIndexOf(model));
    }
    // ...
}

public interface IRepositoryEntity
{
    object Id { get; }
}

public interface IManagedRepositoryEntity : IRepositoryEntity
{
    void SetId(object id);
}
```

That works I guess, but I don't like that `SetId` business. I would like to do something like this instead, but alas, C# won't let me:

```
public interface IRepositoryEntity
{
    virtual object Id { get; }
}

public interface IManagedRepositoryEntity : IRepositoryEntity
{
    override object Id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Also, your code example has a highly unsafe usage of this pattern. `var managedModel = (IManagedRepositoryEntity)model;` Will throw an exception if `model` is not `IManagedRepositoryEntity`. If you want a null return in this situation you need to use the `as` operator.

Answer (score 1):

`virtual` and `override` are not valid in interface definitions, you need

```
public interface IRepositoryEntity
{
   object Id { get; }
}

public interface IManagedRepositoryEntity : IRepositoryEntity
{
    new object Id { get; set; }
}
```